# Android Validation : setError or Toast for instant error show in EditText

Tags: android, validation

I was just wanting to know if there's anyway i can `setError` or `Toast` on an `EditText` instantly after entering values.

For example :

Booking Id(`TextView`)   ***_*__*_*____**(`EditText`)

Now, the value of Booking ID should be exactly 5(not more or less)

So, i've declared this way :

```
if (s6.length()<=4) 
                {
                    bookid.setError( "Enter Booking ID!" );
                    bookid.requestFocus(s6.length());

                }
```

Here s6 represents the `EditText`.

And i was wanting the error to be shown as soon as i enter wrong values(less than 5).

Is there any such way? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a text watcher interface to your EditText and do what you want in `onTextChanged(..)` like:

```
YourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int before, int count) {
                    if(s.length()!=5) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: I think this is incorrect as the count number is not the length of the string but the number of new characters. You should perform a length check on the charsequence instead

Comment: On the CharSequence? I was reading the documentation and I thought count was the number of total characters

Comment: No count is basically the number of characters you just inputed

Comment: I must've not understood.  Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Yeah no worries, in order to do the check here, it should be if(s.length()!=5). Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

To implement a validation mechanism on an EditText, you should have a look at the TextWatcher interface. You can create a class that implements TextWatcher and then assign it to your Edittext. This way you'll gain access to whatever value you have in your editText.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (s6.length()==5) 
{
// do what you wanna do....
}
else
{
bookid.setError( "Enter Booking ID!" );
bookid.requestFocus(s6.length());
}
```